# Catch error before starting the loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, try-catch

Edit: Provided more code.

I have a for-loop that looks like this:

```
public void SendCommand(string userInput)
{
    string[] _command = userInput.Split('#', '>');
    string[] _keypress = _command.Where((value, index) => index % 2 == 0).ToArray(); //Even array = Keypress
    string[] _count = _command.Where((value, index) => index % 2 != 0).ToArray(); // Odd array = keypress count
    int keypressLength = _keypress.GetLength(0);

    for (int j = 0; j < keypressLength; j++) //loop through all indices
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(_count[j]); i++) //repeat convert command for #X times
        {
            ConvertCommand(_keypress[j]);
            Thread.Sleep(100); // wait time after each keypress
        }
    }
}
```

With a 'try-catch' around the above code, if the user input is invalid, an exception will be thrown **halfway** through the loop. However, I want to catch the error before the loop even started, how can I achieve that?

Comment: validate user input and show him a message..if valid entry proceed your loop !

Comment: Without knowing the nature of `ConvertCommand`, we can't possibly know a) how to pre-check that everything will work and b) whether it's even possible to pre-check (i.e. if there's any interaction with external systems, no amount of pre-checking will tell you whether the command will work *by the time* you actually attempt it)

Comment: Which part is the invalid input - `_count[j]` or `_keypress[j]`? And I'd personally perform the parsing once for each iteration of the outer loop rather than once for each iteration of the inner loop...

Comment: Where is the problem on validating the input in front and proceed if it is valid? If any command WITHIn your loop throws an exception how should the application stop BEFORE executing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize `int.TryParse`. It tries to parse a string and returns `true` or `false`:

```
for (int j = 0; j < keypressLength; j++) //loop through all indices
{
    int limit;        
    if (!int.TryParse(_count[j], out limit))
    {
        // Show an error like "_count[j] cannot be parsed"
        continue;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        ConvertCommand(_keypress[j]);
        Thread.Sleep(100); // wait time after each keypress
    }
 }
```

You may also want to implement some sort of validation within `ConvertCommand` if a user keeps entering incorrect data.

**Update:**

> For example, _count[0] can be parsed, but _count[1] can't, by the time it caught the error, _count[0] has already been processed. I don't want any of them to be processed if there will be any error.

You can use the same `int.TryParse` and utilize LINQ to check if all strings in `_count` can be parsed into integers:

```
int stub;
if (_count.Any(x => !int.TryParse(x, out stub)))
{
    // There is a non-integer string somewhere!
}

for (int j = 0; j < keypressLength; j++) //loop through all indices
{
    for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(_count[j]); i++)
    {
        ConvertCommand(_keypress[j]);
        Thread.Sleep(100); // wait time after each keypress
    }
 }
```

Comment: For example, `_count[0]` can be parsed, but `_count[1]` can't, by the time it caught the error, `_count[0]` has already been processed. I don't want any of them to be processed if there will be any error.

Comment: @Liren Check the updated answer.

Comment: THANK YOU! I kept digging into `try-catch` and totally went onto the wrong direction of thoughts.